# Rotating around dodecahedron

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am trying to make a Three.js scene where I've got a dodecahedron. I want the camera to be zoomed in on one side of the dodecahedron and when a button is pressed I want it to zoom out, rotate until it is standing across another side and then zoom in again.

To make this clear:

If the camera would be fully zoomed in on side 1 and I pressed "5", I would want the camera to zoom out - showing the dodecahedron - then rotate towards 5 (or let the dodecahedron rotate side 5 facing the camera?) and zoom in again. It's important that the camera is always set parallel with the base of the pentagon it's facing, not the top or any other rotation.
[image]

I thought it would be smart to start off with just a cube, to not start too complicated. I added some tweens (when pressing G) to illustrate some basic movement, but that doesn't look too good anymore in the fiddle. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InstaK/7y9ozyj6/440/)

Because I feel like I should have a function that does all this movement and calculating for me I first tried to write down each position and rotation each side-view had from the cube so I might detect a pattern. I *can* see some pattern in the values I wrote down for the cube, but I do not know how to convert this into a working function, let alone for a dodecahedron. My noted values are

```
side1 (0, 0,  600) (0, 0, 0)
side2 (600, 0,  0) (0, pi/2, 0)
side3 (0, 0, -600) (0, pi, 0);
side4 (-600, 0, 0) (0, -pi/2, 0);
side5 (0, 600,  0) (-pi/2, 0, 0);
side6 (0, -600, 0) (pi/2, 0, 0);
```

I can see some sort of recurrence happening and some relationships, but I wouldn't see how to link them in a function. I think that would be a first step in getting to a function doing the same but for a more complex shape. Could anyone guide me into some direction I should be looking right now? Because I could of course work with a lot of if clauses, but that's not the correct way to go I feel.

Comment: Hi, I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/craigli/adn8z07e/1/), it seems `keydown` event doesn't work well on jsfiddle, you can export the code to have a look, there are some strange bugs, I'll go on figuring out tomorrow.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of code added. I expected somebody to guide me on the correct path of doing this or giving tips, not nearly make it entirely, haha. Could you elaborate on the choices you made? Because there's kind of a lot going on of which I don't understand why it works.

Comment: This question is very interesting, so I tried for myself. but I haven't figured out the bug, I will share my idea, once I fix the bug, I would update my post to make a complete explanation.

Comment: I also thought of some way I could attack this project and, once I find the time for it, I'll edit my post to show my approach. Maybe together we could get to an even better solution then.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, I'm writing my idea and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, the first we would do is getting the center coordinate of each side of the dodecahedron.

as you know in three.js, a mesh consists of triangles, every triangle has three points, all the faces and vertices can be found in `mesh.geometry.faces` and `mesh.geometry.vertices.` in dodecahedron, each side has three faces and five vertices, and I use each face normal to divide them into 12 groups which have same normal and in the same plane. Then, we got 5 points of each side, calculate the average coordinate to get the center coordinate.

After getting coordinates we need to rotate, one way is rotating the dodecahedron and keep the camera, another way is keeping the dodecahedron and translate camera, in this case, I select the second one. 
[image]

Now camera face to centerA, the green circle is the track of camera, because we need to keep the distance from camera to the dodecahedron center.

To get the target position, we just scale the centerB vector, cause the coordinate of the centerB is object system coordinate, we need to apply the matrix to change the coordinate to world system coordinate.

Then, we translate the camera in an animation,  the camera needs to take an arc.
I use the parametric equation of a circle in 3D space to do that, about the equation you can see [Parametric Equation of a Circle in 3D Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73237/parametric-equation-of-a-circle-in-3d-space). With this formula, I got the parameter θ1 on camera position and θ2 on target position. I update the camera position with θ1 in every animation frame loop.

I add some comments on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/craigli/adn8z07e/3/).(**Still has some bugs, need to update.**)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663593/three-js-earth-and-camera-turning-problems/42687982#42687982) is another solution by keeping the camera and rotate the object.